# How to color the cell based on 2D coordinate and its value? New Excel Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, vba

I am new to Excel EVB, I am just a normal excel user but intend to do some pro stuff. I did some google, yet, I have no clue to start with.

I am trying to create a new excel function that allow user to color the cell based on the X,Y coordinate and its value.

Firstly, I have a predefined X,Y mapping (see below Colum A:E) and Cell C3 is my origin point (0,0).

Secondly, I have a X,Y data table which contain value for each of the (X,Y) coordinate.

[image]

Now, I want to color the X,Y map based on the data from the table with multiple condition.

If Value >= 0 AND <=4E-06, color cell (map) = green, cell value = Value

If Value >4E-06 AND <=9.9E-06, color cell (map) = blue, cell value = Value

If Value >9.9E-6, color cell (map) = red, cell value = Value

Eg.    From the table, if X=1, Y=2, Value = 2.2E-05, the cell D1 will be colored in red and the call value will set to 2.2E-05

[image]

The final result will be look like this:

[image]

Question: How can I create a new excel function based on the above requirement? Any idea and input?

Comment: You can just use this formula to get the values in the cell and apply conditional formatting as per your conditions. `=SUMPRODUCT(($G$2:$G$26=COLUMN()-3)*($H$2:$H$26=ROW()-3)*$I$2:$I$26)`

Comment: You can also use **Conditional Formatting** which is available without the need of any coding except if your function is complex, in which case you could also invoke it from this option.

Answer (score 1):

use the below formula to populate the cells

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($G$2:$G$26=COLUMN()-3)*($H$2:$H$26=-ROW()+3)*$I$2:$I$26)
```

Use conditional formatting to get the desired color in the cell.

[image: Conditional Formatting]

**Formula Explanation as requested:**

`COLUMN()-3` and `-ROW()+3` give you the correct (X,Y) pair in each cell.

`($G$2:$G$26=COLUMN()-3)` checks each cell in the Range G2:G26 and compares to the X value output by COLUMN()-3. this will output and array of TRUE(Where the values match) and FALSE.

`($H$2:$H$26=-ROW()+3)` checks for the Y values.

the product of the above two array will result in an array of 1's and 0's (which is equivalent to TRUE and FALSE). There will be only one 1 in this array as there is only one X,Y pair matching.

This array multiplied( and summed ) by the Values array gives you the final value in the cell.

Comment: Can explain the equation?

Comment: Added the explanation. You can actually go to Formulas tab -> Formula Auditing -> Evaluate Formula to see the calculations in action.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take would be with a sub routine rather than a function. Then iterate down cols G:I with some thing like `while not isempty (.cells (intRow,7).value)`.
On each row you could then set the relevant cells colour property using cols G and H coordinates using offsets from the origin. You can flip the direction by multiplying it by -1 if necessary.
You could use a private function to return the colour from col I value using a select case.
Sorry, not near a computer to write the code but should be easy enough if you know VBA.

Answer (score 0):

your problem like as Battleship, 
my solution is:

```
Sub Battleship()
Dim cc As Range 'set center cell
Dim arrVal() As Variant
Dim lrw As Integer
lrw = ActiveSheet().Range("G2").End(xlDown).Row
arrVal = Range("G2:I" & lrw)
Set cc = Range("C3")

For i = 1 To UBound(arrVal())
    cc.Offset(arrVal(i, 1), arrVal(i, 2)).Select
        Selection.Value = arrVal(i, 3)
    Select Case arrVal(i, 3)
    Case 0 To 0.000004
        Selection.Interior.Color = 5296274
    Case 0.000004 To 0.0000099
        Selection.Interior.Color = 15773696
    Case Is > 0.0000099
        Selection.Interior.Color = 255
    End Select
Next i

End Sub
```